# Why are property accessor methods different for Immutable Maps and Records?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using Immutable JS in conjunction with React + Redux. For the most part I really love how it reinforces the Redux paradigm, with the exception of its property accessor methods.

For Immutable `Map`s, one must access properties using the Immutable `get` method.

Ex. `this.props.exampleMap.get('mapProperty');`

However, for Immutable `Record`s, there is no get method. Instead you just access properties with the dot method as with normal JS objects.

Ex. `this.props.exampleRecord.recordProperty`

My question is, why is there this discrepancy? This is making me a little OCD because my components are now filled with a mix of both methods and frankly it's a little ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can use `.get(...)` for immutable records. The way I think of is that records have additional nicer syntax by allowing you to access the properties directly.

If you [take a look at the type definitions](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/v3.8.1/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L1135) of a record, you'll see that record constructors create objects with types `Immutable.Map<string, any>`.

---

This nicer syntax is possible because you predefine the properties of the record upon creation.

Here is the immutable record creation example taken [directly from their docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record)

> ```
> const { Record } = require('immutable')
> const ABRecord = Record({ a: 1, b: 2 })
> const myRecord = new ABRecord({ b: 3 })
> ```

So remember, you give the `Record` function an object with default values and it returns a constructor you can use to create object with `new`.

Comment: I didn't actually know `Record` had a `.get()` method (my bad for not properly checking the docs!) Although I don't love the using `.get()` since IMO it makes accessing properties more verbose, I will probably just use it for `Record`s and `Map`s for consistency. 

An added benefit is it's always clear when you're working with an Immutable  object.

Comment: if you're using typescript or any editor that can read type definitions, you should be able to highlight over the immutable object to get the type and methods too. ImmutableJS 4 is coming soon and that'll add really good typings for records